# Why isn't the relativistic jet visible in the image of the M87 black hole?

Tags: black-hole, radio-astronomy, m87, astronomical-jet

I'm referring to the infamous relativistic jet, which consists of matter being accelerated to near the speed of light, originating at the poles of the black hole:

[image]

But in the image of the black hole in the radio spectrum nothing of the sort is visible:

[image]

I would expect the relativistic jet to be one of the most prominent features since it's accelerated much more that other material orbiting the black hole.

Is it because the jet is more prominently visible in the visible and infrared spectrum than in the radio spectrum?

Comment: I think you need to look into the scale of the images. The radio image is a massively "zoomed in" view of the centre of the bright dot at the top left of the other image. So most of the jet would be out of the picture. Whether there is a part that close to the SMBH and it's simply too dim, or too distorted, to see or whether the jet actually starts a bit further away, I don't know.

Comment: actually what is the scale difference on the two images?  10 million to 1 ?  :O

Comment: I just answered this on Physics SE and feel reluctant to just copy it here.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/472910/why-is-there-no-jet-visible-in-the-m87-black-hole-radio-image/472943#472943